# mysql communication link failure on 2 laptops

Tags: java, mysql

I have made a software, I have made the mysql database on the different laptop, and the software on different laptop, means i have 2 laptops one has software and one has database and both are connected with internet wire. now I am connecting my software with the database which is installed on different laptop but I get a communication failure link. I have given the ip address of the server laptop, but yet i get the error, please tell me how to resolve this issue, the code is here.

```
    private static void init()throws Exception{

    String url="jdbc:mysql://169.254.96.182:3306/content_management_system";
    String user="root";
    String password="oracle";

    con=DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

    System.out.println("connection successfull");
}//end method
```

and the errror is

```
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:341)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2189)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2222)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2017)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:779)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
```

Comment: did you ping the IP from the client laptop?

Comment: what is this, i don't know about this

Comment: I mean use in your cmd `>ping 169.254.96.182` and check if there are a response or not

Comment: @YCF_L I have changed my ip address on the server computer, i have changed to 192.168.0.1, and then i pinged that ip address from client computer then i got a response (Ping Statistics for 192.168.0.1: Packets sent=4, received=4, lost=0 (0% loss), now what do I do

Comment: @YCF_L please tell me what to do, its my final year project and I have to submit it tomorrow ??

Comment: I'm not sure but can you try using a cable instead of WiFi?

Comment: @YCF_L I am using cable not wifi, but still getting the error

Comment: try to use a new jdbc driver try with this version http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommysqljdbc515jar.htm

Answer (score 0):

By default, the port 3306; which you are using to route the connection to your database, will be closed - or at least, blocked from any outside connections.

You'll need to open this port; and potentially add port forwarding to ensure any outside connections are directed properly.

Look up how to open ports and check out this [link](https://portforward.com/store/pfconfig.cgi?advertid=1) on port forwarding.

As mentioned in the comments you can also use the command `PING 169.254.96.182` to check if a connection can be established!

Also if you do open the port, unless you have strict security measures in place; you should remove your IP from this question as you're basically giving us all access!

Comment: I have changed my ip address on the server computer, i have changed to 192.168.0.1, and then i pinged that ip address from client computer then i got a response (Ping Statistics for 192.168.0.1: Packets sent=4, received=4, lost=0 (0% loss)